# PDO com tipo BIT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estava agora fazendo uma instrução com *on duplicate* e tenho alguns campos tipo `BIT`. Minha classe *DB* faz a tipagem usando `PDO::PARAM_STR`, `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`, `PDO::PARAM_INT`... mas o uso destas constantes é opcional, e quando não informado segue o padrão do `PDO`.

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column *'CAMPO'* at row 1' in [ ... ]

Eu omiti a constantes na hora de executar, então foi com o valor default, mas recebi a mensagem de erro acima. O valor passado foi um inteiro `1` - não uma string `'1'`.

Estou querendo entender a diferença entre `1` tipo *int* e `1` tipo *str*. Como o *MYSQL* recebe o mesmo número e sabe que um é string e outro é um integer?

Comment: eu tive um problema muito semelhante, a causa era o driver do PDO, lembro esse erro acontece somente em algumas versões, você pode adicionar as versões do PHP e MySQL?

Comment: *PHP* : 5.4.28, *MYSQL* : 5.5.36-log

Answer (score 1):

Se conseguires fazer a query no mysql é só passar as querys crias uma tabela.

algo do genero

/* vai te dar um campo que estiver  nulo na tabela
 SELECT ISNULL(CAST(TEMP AS BIT),0) AS ESTADO

depois no where comparas com not null ou null

Comment: Acho que isso não responde a minha pergunta...